# How can I send the write attribute of a NiFi processor to next processor?

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I am using GetHDFSEvents processor to know hdfs.inotify.event.path. I need to get notified of the path when an new file is created in hdfs. How can I pass the attribute hdfs.inotify.event.path to the next processor to execute a shell script based on the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ListHDFS processor and use Fetchhdfs or ExecuteStream command processor. Use Expression language ${path}/${filename}

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.ListHDFS/index.html) and path attribut instead of GetHDFS if you just want to be notified.

Comment: How to pass the path from ListHDFS to GetHDFS?

Comment: you can't. if you use listHDFS so you should use listHDFS -> fetchHDFS pattern.
listHDFS will write the absolute path and filename as attribut of flowfile : ${absolute.path} and ${filename}. look at the documentaiton under "Writes Attributes" section.